Problem (9.19) - Character theory of finite groups (Martin Isaacs)
I am currently reading chapters $9$, $10$ et $15$ of Isaacs' character theory of finite groups and I am stuck with this question on splitting field.
In this case, I have to found a splitting field for $H_8$ the quaternion group $E\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ $($i.e. a subfield on which every irreducible representations of $H_8$ are similar to the ones on $\mathbb{C})$ such that there is no sub-splitting field $K$ such that $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq K\subseteq E$ with $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is finite.
It is known that if $E = \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, there always exist such a subfield. So $E$ has to be a non algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. In his book, he gives as a hint that we should search for a field of the form $E = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two transcendentals.
I have absolutely no clue to solve this problem, so any help or idea would be very much appreciated.

Over $\mathbb C$, $Q_8$ has $4$ irreducible representaitons of dimension $1$ (factors through $Q_8/\{\pm 1\}\simeq\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$), and they are all taking values in $\{\pm 1\}$ hence over $\mathbb Q$. We only need to find a field $E$ that can host a two dimensional irreducible representation $\rho$. Obviously $\rho(\pm 1) = \pm I_2$, and we only need to figure out the image of $i, j, k$.
Here is an example:
$$\rho(i)=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & -a \end{pmatrix}, \rho(j)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \rho(k)=\begin{pmatrix} -b & a \\ a & b\end{pmatrix}$$
where $a,b$ satisfies $a^2+b^2=-1$.
How to come up with this? Well, $A=\rho(i)$ satisfies $x^2=-1$, hence $\operatorname{trace}(A)=0, \det A = 1$, so we may assume $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -\frac{1+a^2}{b} & -a \end{pmatrix}$. Similarly $B=\rho(j)$ also satisfies the same property, and now we have $\rho(k)=AB$ must have $\det=1$, thus we only have to figure out how to make $\operatorname{trace}(AB)=0$. And in the process we can make some assumptions to simplify the search.
We may pick an arbitrary transcendental number $a\in\mathbb C$, and then choose $b$ accordingly. Let $E=\mathbb Q(a, b)$, and we show there is no $K\subset E$ such that $[E:\mathbb Q]<\infty$. That is, there is no algebraic element in $E$ other than all of $\mathbb Q$. Indeed, since $b^2=-1-a^2$, each (algebraic) element in $E$ can be expressed as $f(a)+g(a)b$, where $f, g\in \mathbb Q(a)$. Note that $a\mapsto a, b\mapsto -b$ is in the Galois group of $E/\mathbb Q$, thus $f(a)-g(a)b$ is also algebraic. Hence $g(a)b$ is algebraic, therefore $(g(a)b)^2=g(a)^2(-a^2-1)\in\mathbb Q(a)$ is algebraic which can only be rational. That is we have $g(a)=\frac{r(a)}{s(a)}, \gcd(r,s)=1$ and $\frac{r(a)^2(a^2+1)}{s(a)^2}\in\mathbb Q$, so $s(a)^2 \mid a^2+1$, but $a^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ (as a polynomial of  the transcendental $a$).
